Trigger GitLab DAST scan from external pipeline
I want to use GitLab only for DAST scans. I have some existing pipelines(Jenkins, Azure devops ). I would like to run DAST scans using Gitlab's DAST scanner. What are my options? I do not want any  repository on Gitlab, and no Gitlab pipeline for code build or deploy stages, but want a way to configure proejects DAST scanner profile and trigger DAST scan through API from external pipelines.
